# sqlalchemy connect to databasename with whitespace

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to connect to a postgres-DB, which unfortunately has a name with a whitespace in it:

```
%load_ext sql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
%sql postgresql://postgres:dbpass@localhost/Test DB

(psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  database "Test DB" does not exist
```

I've tried to follow some tipps on the internet and used:

```
import urllib.parse
urllib.parse.quote_plus("Test DB")
```

which simply results in a string "Test+DB" (this does not work).

How can I adress the database, without changing its name?

Best regards!

Comment: Does `//postgres:dbpass@localhost/"Test DB"` work? But you should really avoid any identifier (including database names) that require quoting to begin with.

Comment: No, that also does not work. Yes, I'd never chose to do it that way, but I'm not the owner/admin of the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it by using sqlalchemy's **create_engine()**, therefore being able to simply save the string (with its whitespace) as a variable (eg *database_name*):

```
import sqlalchemy as db
database_name = 'Test DB'
engine = db.create_engine('postgresql://' + 'user_name' + ':' + 'password' + '@localhost/' + database_name)
connection = engine.connect()
s = 'SELECT id FROM user'
df = pd.read_sql_query(s, engine)
df.head()
```

Hope it helps, best regards.